# jQuery Plugin: Nested Sortable Components

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to move from old Scriptaculous code to jQuery.

Here is a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jpencausse/ZmQV6/

```
  <div class='column'>
    <div class='box'>...</div>
    <div class='box'>
      <div class='handle'><h3>Box Title</h3></div>
      <div class='box-body'>

        <ul>
          <li>Item 1</li>    
          <li>Item 2
            <ul>
              <li>Item 2-1</li>
              <li>Item 2-2</li>
              <li>Item 2-3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Item 3</li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class='column'>...</div>
```

**I'm looking for a jQuery Plugin:**

1. Sorting between .box in a column or connected with other columns
2. Sorting between UL/LI (if boxes have a handle)
3. Nested Sorting of UL/LI
4. Compatible IE7+, FF, Chrome (could be IE9+)
5. Without the weight of jQuery UI

**Known library:**

- html5sortable  => Can't do 2. and 3.
- nestedSortable => Can't do 5. not sure for 2. + 3.
- jquery.nestable.js => Not sure for 2.

Any ideas ?

At least a way to use html5sortable  (clean API) with .box and nested UL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this? it takes advantage of jQuery UI sortable/drag & drop

http://imstillreallybored.com/music/widgets/

Comment: No, 5) Without the weight of jQuery UI and do not know if it works nested

Comment: It works nested and In my example I have a custom jQuery UI file with only what is needed for example included.

Comment: this is also a really good plugin that does nesting but also uses jQuery UI

Comment: Jean-Philippe, jQuery UI is not bad if you only use what is necessary for the sortable and drag&drop. You won't be needing Widgets or Effects.

Comment: I agree but if I can skip the 1211 line (less if minified) of the jquery-ui-perso it would be better :-). html5sortable is only 93 lines .